# Hill Cipher if the length of the string is not divisible by the Key Dimensions

Tags: hill-cipher

For a project, I want to encode the word "MEMBRANOPHONES" with the key "MULTITONE". I try spliting "MEMBRANOPHONES" into groups of 3, but then I get "MEM", "BRA", "NOP", "HON", leaving me with a 2 letter "ES". I can't multiply a 3 by 3 matrix by a 2 by 1 matrix, so what do I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard problem in modern cryptography (eg for [CBC-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#CBC)).

The standard solution is to use [*Padding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) or some other agreed-upon mechanism to encode variable-length messages as a multiple of the blocksize.

The most common padding is PKCS#7 padding: If one byte is left, append `0x01`, if two are left append `0x02 0x02` and so on. Note that this requires you to also pad on messages which are a multiple of the blocksize (in case your message ends on eg `0x01`).

As you are more concerned with letters than bytes, you can probably adapt the above scheme to use `A` instead of `0x01` and `B` instead of `0x02` and so on for the full alphabet. So in your particular case you would pad the message with a single A.